# How to skip records in SqlAlchemy query?

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I have 100 rows in my DB. I'm trying to execute select query but I want to skip the first 10 rows (i.e. I want rows in range 11-20).

How can I do this?

Comment: Study Limit offset and try to search before posting the question!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The raw SQL is like:

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

In SqlAlchemy language it's like:

```
Table.query.limit(10).offset(10).all()
```

Comment: This is SQL, not SQLAlchemy.

Comment: result = Doctors.query.all() - it's my query but this query fetchs all records. Can you write your query in this format? Thatns.

Comment: This is wrong, it should be `Table.query.limit(10).offset(10).all()`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [limit()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.limit) and [offset()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.offset), like this:

```
foos = session.query(Foo).offset(10).limit(10)
```

Which will construct a query like this:

```
select * from foos offset 10 limit 10
```